# Existing Java project dependency in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, module, dependencies

I'd like to add my Java project as dependency of my Android project. The Java project is not yet compiled to library, I work on it parallel. So if I change anything in the Java project I want to see the change in my Android project as well.

I tried to add my Java project to the Android App as a module, but it didn't became top level module and this action copied all the files from the existing place into the new module folder. I don't want to duplicate the code, I'd use a module as reference to the existing project's folder.